# How to download a file from a website in C#

Tags: c#, download, windows

Is it possible to download a file from a website in Windows Application form and put it into a certain directory?

Comment: Mitch's comment is the most direct and most accurate answer, lol!

Comment: Unless you are new to .net, I would suggest searching the MSDN documentation would help. Look for things that you want to achieve, lok at what namespace this might fit in & see if there is a class which can do that :)

Comment: @shahkalpesh - to heck with that... just google for: +C# +"download file"

Comment: @Marc: Oh sure. I don't mean to let the OP search in MSDN. The idea is to look out for docs first, google next & then post questions - if none of it helps. I mean what is the point of asking questions for which you can find something on google already?

Comment: The idea of this site is not to tell people to google for their answers, the idea of this site is for people to ask questions despite how stupid they are so that when people google in the future the answer will be right here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download a file from a URL in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307688/how-to-download-a-file-from-a-url-in-c)

Answer (score 121, accepted):

With the [WebClient class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx):

```
using System.Net;
//...
WebClient Client = new WebClient ();
Client.DownloadFile("http://i.stackoverflow.com/Content/Img/stackoverflow-logo-250.png", @"C:\folder\stackoverflowlogo.png");
```

Comment: How do you download the file into a folder relative to the application installation's directory ? (since your download path is  hardcoded)

Comment: @Tareck117 AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "myname"

Comment: Is there way to ask for save/open in browser using webclient like Response.BinaryWrite ?

Answer (score 87):

Use [`WebClient.DownloadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfile.aspx):

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile("http://csharpindepth.com/Reviews.aspx", 
                        @"c:\Users\Jon\Test\foo.txt");
}
```

Comment: SKEEEEEEEEEEEEEET!

Comment: Don't forget IDisposable ;-p But (other than a "using") that is exactly what I came in to write...

Comment: Ah, normal service by the pedants is resumed ;-p

Comment: Add an async version to the answer? I don't dare to edit a Skeet post.

Comment: @JohanLarsson: I don't think it's worth revisiting all `WebClient` answers from years ago to show async versions.

Comment: +1 for the use of [Using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) keyword.

Comment: This version is correct, because IDisposable object should be used in "usiing" statement.

Answer (score 19):

You may need to know the status during the file download or use credentials before making the request.

**Here is an example that covers these options:**

```
Uri ur = new Uri("http://remotehost.do/images/img.jpg");

using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
    //client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
    String credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Username" + ":" + "MyNewPassword"));
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = $"Basic {credentials}";

    client.DownloadProgressChanged += WebClientDownloadProgressChanged;
    client.DownloadDataCompleted += WebClientDownloadCompleted;
    client.DownloadFileAsync(ur, @"C:\path\newImage.jpg");
}
```

And the callback's functions implemented as follows:

```
void WebClientDownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Download status: {0}%.", e.ProgressPercentage);

    // updating the UI
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
        progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    });
}

void WebClientDownloadCompleted(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Download finished!");
}
```

**(Ver 2) - Lambda notation: other possible option for handling the events**

```
client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(delegate(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e) {
    Console.WriteLine("Download status: {0}%.", e.ProgressPercentage);

    // updating the UI
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
        progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    });
});

client.DownloadDataCompleted += new DownloadDataCompletedEventHandler(delegate(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e){
    Console.WriteLine("Download finished!");
});
```

**(Ver 3) - We can do better**

```
client.DownloadProgressChanged += (object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Download status: {0}%.", e.ProgressPercentage);

    // updating the UI
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
        progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    });
};

client.DownloadDataCompleted += (object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e) => 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Download finished!");
};
```

**(Ver 4) - Or**

```
client.DownloadProgressChanged += (o, e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Download status: {e.ProgressPercentage}%.");

    // updating the UI
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
        progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    });
};

client.DownloadDataCompleted += (o, e) => 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Download finished!");
};
```

Comment: If you want to use `async Task` instead of `async void` look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16514441/2816057) which uses `await webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(...)` so no need for a `DownloadDataCompleted` event

Answer (score 13):

Sure, you just use a [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(VS.71).aspx).

Once you have the `HttpWebRequest` set up, you can save the response stream to a file `StreamWriter`(Either `BinaryWriter`, or a `TextWriter` depending on the mimetype.) and you have a file on your hard drive.

EDIT: Forgot about `WebClient`. That works good unless as long as you only need to use `GET` to retrieve your file. If the site requires you to `POST` information to it, you'll have to use a `HttpWebRequest`, so I'm leaving my answer up.

Comment: I dont want to read it back from a slow hd..  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code to Download file from a WebSite to Desktop:

```
using System.Net;

WebClient client = new WebClient ();
client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://www.Address.com/File.zip"), Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "File.zip");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```
public void TheDownload(string path)
{
  System.IO.FileInfo toDownload = new System.IO.FileInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path));

  HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
  HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
             "attachment; filename=" + toDownload.Name);
  HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length",
             toDownload.Length.ToString());
  HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
  HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(path);
  HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

The implementation is done in the follows:

```
TheDownload("@"c:\Temporal\Test.txt"");
```

Source: http://www.systemdeveloper.info/2014/03/force-downloading-file-from-c.html

Comment: your code sample looks like a web-server's method to send a file to a client...

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use `DownloadFileAsync` method in `WebClient` class. It downloads to a local file the resource with the specified `URI`. Also this method does not block the calling thread.

Sample:

```
    webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://www.example.com/file/test.jpg"), "test.jpg");
```

**For more information:**

> http://csharpexamples.com/download-files-synchronous-asynchronous-url-c/