# How to download a file to a specific path in from a given url in a windows form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I need to download pdf files from a specified links(url) to a specific folder in a windows application using winforms please any one can suggest me with a solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to download a file from a website in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525364/how-to-download-a-file-from-a-website-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 32):

```
using System.Net;

using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.DownloadFile("http://mysite.com/myfile.txt", @"c:\myfile.txt");
}
```

Comment: I test it, path can be included in filename. its Correct

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [WebClient.DownloadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx) method, available since .NET 2.0. It is usable from any type of application, not just Winforms.

You should be aware that DownloadFile blocks until the entire file finishes downloading. To avoid blocking you can use the [WebClient.DownloadFileAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144196.aspx) method that will download in the background and raise the [DownloadFileCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfilecompleted.aspx) event when downloading finishes

Answer (score 6):

You could just "search the web" (aka google) for "C# download file", and end up with [this simple MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfile%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (modified to fit your specific question):

```
string remoteUri = "http://www.test.com/somefile.pdf";
string fileName = "c:\\targetfolder\\somefile.pdf";

WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
myWebClient.DownloadFile(remoteUri,fileName);
```

Comment: Funny remark... Many people do this (me included), _avoid_ MSDN references and go _directly_ to a stackoverflow post.

Comment: How can i download from a path like this \\appsupld\Uploads\OfficeAutomation\OMA\Downloads\ instead of a http path. When i try it i am getting file not found exception?

Answer (score 0):

```
myWebClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource,fileName);
```

If not the Target path is not specified and if you give it like `file.abc` it is  downloaded to a path called `Application.StartupPath` as the name of `file.abc`
So you just have to give your specific path like `@"C:\\Folder1\\Folder2\\file.abc"`

I think this will help a bit more. I could not get it at first site of  sample codes provided by MSDN and at last i found this.