# C# WebClient download file to absolute path

Tags: c#, webclient

I'm working with ASP.NET Core and try to download a file to an absolute path.

But the problem I have is that the file always gets downloaded to the project directory and the filename itself gets the name of the whole path.

My Code:

```
string path = @"C:\Users\User\file.txt";
string url = "https://example.com/file.txt";
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile(url, path);
}
```

With this code the file gets then saved in the project folder with the file name `C:\Users\User\file.txt`, instead of being saved in the directory `C:\Users\User` with the file name `file.txt`.

The backslashes and the colon get replaced with some special characters, because they are not allowed in the filename.

Answer (score 3):

#### Update

This worked for me:

```cs
using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
    client.DownloadFile("https://localhost:5001/", @"D:\file.html");
}
```

According to this and [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9096123/6789816), your absolute path should work. Are you certain your path is formatted correctly and the destination folder exists?

#### Original Answer

*Use this if all else fails, since saving to a valid folder should work.*

`WebClient.DownloadFile` will download to the location of the current application (specified by `Application.Startup`) for a relative path. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfile?view=net-5.0):

> #### Parameters
>
> `address Uri`
> The URI specified as a String, from which to download data.
>
> `fileName String`
> The name of the local file that is to receive the data.

If you are going to use `WebClient`, you will need to move the file after you have downloaded it, e.g.

```cs
// Download to a local file.
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile(url, fileName);
}

// Get the full path of the download and the destination folder.
string fromPath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, fileName);
string toPath = Path.Combine(destinationFolder, fileName);

// Move the file.
File.Move(fromPath, toPath);
```