# Download multiple files async and wait for all of them to finish before executing the rest of the code

Tags: c#, download, async-await, console-application

I am trying to download multiple files from the internet and await for all of them to finish.  This is a C# console application that I am running, so no progress bar event handler should be necessary.  However it currently just continues to execute code even though all files have not been downloaded.

- 1.Downloading all files!
- 2.Finished Download File A
- 3.Finished Downloading all files!
- 4.Finished Downloading File B
- 5.Finished Downloading File C

How would you await till all async download files are finished.

```
 private void DownloadMultipleFiles(List<DocumentObject> doclist)
    {
        foreach(var value in doclist){
            try
            {
                using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
                {
                    string downloadToDirectory = @Resources.defaultDirectory + value.docName;
                    webClient.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
                    webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += client_DownloadFileCompleted;
                    webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(value.docUrl), @downloadToDirectory);

                    //Add them to the local
                    Context.listOfLocalDirectories.Add(downloadToDirectory);
                }         
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Errors.printError("Failed to download File: " + value.docName);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The `DownloadFileAsync`/`DownloadFileCompleted` members of `WebClient` use the [Event-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969.aspx). If you want to use `async` and `await`, you should be using the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx).

In this case, you should use the [`DownloadFileTaskAsync` member](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193917.aspx), as such:

```
private async Task DownloadFileAsync(DocumentObject doc)
{
  try
  {
    using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
    {
      string downloadToDirectory = @Resources.defaultDirectory + doc.docName;
      webClient.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
      await webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(doc.docUrl), @downloadToDirectory);

      //Add them to the local
      Context.listOfLocalDirectories.Add(downloadToDirectory);
    }         
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
    Errors.printError("Failed to download File: " + doc.docName);
  }
}

private async Task DownloadMultipleFilesAsync(List<DocumentObject> doclist)
{
  await Task.WhenAll(doclist.Select(doc => DownloadFileAsync(doc)));
}
```

Please note that your `Context.listOfLocalDirectories.Add` and `Errors.printError` methods should be threadsafe.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up.  Made sure my localDirectories is thread safe added my own completion event handler as well.  Thank you for all the help.  This also helped me understand the problems with my other async tasks as well.

Comment: This is available since 4.5

Comment: Does the exception failed to download file get thrown if the URL that is attempting to be downloaded from returns a 404 Not Found?

Comment: @MikeUpjohn: I believe so, yes. `WebClient` will raise an exception for any non-success response code.