# How do I get my C# Async and Wait code to work?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

Can someone please help me with this
here is my code, I want to make the unzip task wait for the file to download but its not an  and it doesn't let me await a void, Ive looked everywhere and i cant figure it out so can someone send me back the working code thanks (note all this code works but not with async):

```
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
        client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("https://webserver-test-1.000webhostapp.com/spacelightzipped.zip"), Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\spacelightzipped.zip");

        String ZipPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\spacelightzipped.zip";
        String extractPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(ZipPath, extractPath);

        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process
        {
            EnableRaisingEvents = false
        };
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\SpaceLightApp.exe";
        proc.Start();
```

Comment: _"it doesn't let me await a void"_ You can use just Task instead of void, so that you can await in the place where you are invoking it.

Comment: @Thangadurai - I think the OP is referring to [`DownloadFileAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144196(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: If you want to see all of my code it is [here](https://webserver-test-1.000webhostapp.com/codeasyncandwait.txt)

Comment: You may wish to look at [`DownloadFileTaskAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193917(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, Ah..sorry I missed that point. This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514027/download-multiple-files-async-and-wait-for-all-of-them-to-finish-before-executin) post provides a workaround.

Comment: @Thangadurai i tried that but I get new errors, can someone like edit it so that it works thx [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ysfm4xlm7w9qze6/Screenshot%202018-06-23%2014.21.13.png?dl=0)

Comment: Please EDIT your question and rephrase exactly what is your issue. As it is described right now, it is quite unclear what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the event [WebClient.DownloadFileCompleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfilecompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) Event which will be raised when the file is completely downloaded, then execute whatever code you want on the file.

So you need to register the event for your webClient.
like :

```
client.DownloadFileCompleted += wc_DownloadFileCompleted;
```

Then call your code to extract and execute in the DownloadFileCompleted event.

```
private static void wc_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            String ZipPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\spacelightzipped.zip";
            String extractPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(ZipPath, extractPath);

            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process
              {
                 EnableRaisingEvents = false
              };
             proc.StartInfo.FileName = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\SpaceLightApp.exe";
             proc.Start();
        }
```