# how to save XML URL content into text file using C#

Tags: c#, xml

I want to save Xml Url content into text file using C# 
I tried this code

```
System.Xml.XmlTextReader _XmlTextReader = new System.Xml.XmlTextReader("http://www.w3schools.com/php/links.xml");
        string_xmlContent =_XmlTextReader.Readinnerxml();
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\users\vaio\desktop\new folder");
```

but it didn't work**

PS: sorry my English not very well

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to download a file from a website in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525364/how-to-download-a-file-from-a-website-in-c-sharp)

Comment: "it didn't work" is not a question anyone can answer. You have to tell us what happened, what you expected to happen, and why you think the two are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load("http://www.w3schools.com/php/links.xml");

File.WriteAllText("c:\\links.xml", document.InnerXml);
```

Comment: can i have ur Email to i can send u my program