# How to download a file from server using its path from withing a child gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, attachment

I have a nested scenario with gridview and there is a requirement of downloading a file from the child gridview.

I am fetching the path but not getting an appropriate way to download the file as it has different types, like .xls,.docx,.png,.jpg etc.

here is a snip of Grid

[image: Attachment is a link button to download file]

```
protected void GridView2_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "AttachDownload")
        {
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            string url = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
            byte[] bytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);
            string fileName = e.CommandSource.ToString();
            // Response.ContentType = "image/png";
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
            Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
            Response.End();

            // ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Download Attachment')", true);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { lblErrorText.Text = ex.ToString(); }

}
```

The Row command event is fired and command argument is the file's name.

Comment: There are several ways to download files from websites. 
Did you search stackoverflow for examples?
One quick search gave me this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525364/how-to-download-a-file-from-a-website-in-c-sharp

Comment: Why not store the filename with extension as a CommandArgument?

Comment: @Christian, mate i suppose u didnt read my question  properly, i asked for the way to download files with different extentions.

Comment: Whatever extension you want to download is irrelevant at this point - you supply the full path and the browser takes care of the rest.
If you don't know the extension, you should lookup that first.