# How to download a flash video to my computer

Tags: flash, download

I have a Flash video on my website, like so:

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" width="356" height="300" align="middle">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain">
<param name="movie" value="swf/video-310.swf"><param name="quality" value="high"><param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff"><embed src="swf/video-310.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="356" height="300" align="middle" allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">
</object>
```

How can I use an input button or even a link to download this video to my computer?

Comment: Right Click and Save As.

Comment: how can i use an input button or even a link to download this video to my computer?

Comment: What about using System.Net.WebClient:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307688/how-to-download-a-file-from-a-url-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="button" name="Button" value="Download Flash Movie!" onClick="window.open('http://www.yoursite.com/swf/video-310.swf', 'download'); return false;">
```

This is maybe how I would do it. Hope this helps.