# Copy image from server to my server using its URL C#

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

I'm trying to copy image from onther server to my server using image url. and here is my code

```
 internal Boolean changePhoto(int userID, string imagePath)
    {
        Boolean success = true;

        try
        {
            string fileName = Convert.ToString(userID) + ".jpg";

            var currentApplicationPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath;
            currentApplicationPath += "/Images/profiles/";

            var fullFilePath = imagePath;


            // Get the destination path
            var copyToPath = currentApplicationPath + fileName;

            // Copy the file
            System.IO.File.Copy(fullFilePath, copyToPath,true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DAO.exDao myDao = new DAO.exDao();
            myDao.insert(ex);
            success = false;
        }

        return success;

    }
```

But i have an exception which is

```
URI formats are not supported.
```

The previous method take the user id that will be the file name and take the source of the image that will copy to my server, and when i call it the exception appear.

Comment: Use the debugger to see what the values of the URI's are before it is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`File.Copy` inclines you that you cannot use web urls to copy files.

However, there is [another approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/308336/558018):

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.DownloadFile(fullFilePath, copyToPath);
}
```

That **will** download it. However, it does not support local files.

Comment: In fact, it DOES support local files :)

Comment: It's true; it supports local files. Awesome! That helped a lot!