# C# The name 'client' does not exist in the current context // Identifier expected // Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct

Tags: c#, html

Im extremely noob in C#. Could you please help me?

I get the following errors:

- The name 'client' does not exist in the current context
- Identifier expected
- Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct

Could you please write me the code that could work properly. I really appreciate your help in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using (WebClient client = new WebClient ());

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         client.DownloadFile("http://yoursite.com/page.html", @"C:\localfile.html");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: `"The name 'client' does not exist in the current context"` means "The name 'client' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: [please see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307688/how-to-download-a-file-from-a-url-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

You've got this:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient ());
```

in the list of `using` *directives* when you really meant it to be a using *statement* in the method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
       client.DownloadFile("http://yoursite.com/page.html",
                           @"C:\localfile.html");
    }
}
```

Basically the `using` keyword has two different meanings in C#:

- `using` directives import namespaces and allow type aliases. For example:

  ```
  using System; // Imports the System namespace
  using Cons = System.Console; // Creates an alias for the System.Console type
  ```
- `using` statements allow a resource to be easily wrapped in a try/finally block to dispose of the resource at the end of the statement:

  ```
  using (SomeResource resource = new SomeResource(...))
  {
      // Use the resource here; it will be disposed of automatically at the
      // end of the block.
  }
  ```