# Download a file in c# via url when file type and file name is unknown

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is related to [How to download a file from a URL in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307688/how-to-download-a-file-from-a-url-in-c) but in my case the url dosen't have file name included in url. suppose a url www.test.com/files0 is a file and in the browser it gets downloaded as 123.mpg how can i save it on server with the same name and extention?

Basically, I want to get filename and type before downloading the file from url and only download the file if it is an allowed extension.

Comment: I don't think a server will even allow you to download a file with out the filename / full path to the file.

Comment: You should have file name in respons header `Content-Disposition`

Comment: No extension will be an unknown MIME type. If IIS isn't set up to serve this you won't be able to download it...

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you're using the `HttpClient` class to make your request, You can use the `HttpResponseMessage` that your query returns to decide if you want to download the file or not.  For example:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://MySite/my/download/path").ConfigureAwait(false);

if (!String.Equals(response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.DispositionType, "attachment", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
  return;
}

// Call some method that will check if the file extension and/or media type 
// of the file are acceptable.
if (!IsAllowedDownload(response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName, response.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType)) {
  return;
}

// Call some method that will take a stream containing the response payload 
// and write it somewhere.
WriteResponseStream(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false));
```