# Download a file using C# from a URL into a MVC.Net Application directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url

How Can I download a file from a url, let's say:

```
https://example-my.sharepoint.com/personal/Documents/MyExample.docx
```

using c# and save it in a folder into my MVC Application on the server. Is there any way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: I can't comment because not enough 50 reputation.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307688/how-to-download-a-file-from-a-url-in-c

Comment: Thanks @DangKhoa ,  that is what I was looking for...