# How to load Dicom image from server (path contains https://)

Tags: c#, dicom, fo-dicom

How to load Dicom image from server (path contains https://)
Am using fo-Diocm library.

```
var image = new DicomImage(filePath);
```

if filePath is from local directory its working fine.
if filePath is from server (like https://example.com/filepath.dcm), its throwing  'Dicom.DicomFileException' saying that specified path value is not correct.
What is the right way to load DicomImage from server ??

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK: Not at all. Obtaining DICOM Files through Web API is referred to as WADO (Web Access to DICOM Objects), and there is an [open feature request](https://github.com/fo-dicom/fo-dicom/issues/127) in fo-dicom to support this, but it has been assigned quite a [high priority](https://github.com/fo-dicom/fo-dicom/wiki/Priorities).

However, the URL https://example.com/filepath.dcm does not adhere to WADO encoding, so maybe you cannot use a DICOM communication protocol to obtain the image (or you do not want to). But in this case, your task is simply "downloading a file from an URL" and not related to DICOM at all. After the download is completed, you have it stored locally, and can go on with local file access as you are used to.

The "missing link": [How to download a file from an URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307688/how-to-download-a-file-from-a-url-in-c)

Comment: Few other tool kits do support this though. IMHO, WADO was designed for integration purposes instead of developing full featured DICOM Image Viewer. But yes; if [tag:fo-dicom] is the only way to go then WADO is an answer at least for now until feature is implemented by tool kit.

Comment: Interesting assessment. I'd say WADO is designed for incorporating DICOM in web based products, because it fits much better into the development environment and the technical infrastructure than the binary TCP based protocols from the early 90s

Comment: Agreed and I actually do not mean that. I mean WADO is still not as widely accepted as TCP/FileSystem based implementation. It is mostly used when PACS needs to share the viewer with other software basically for display purpose only; that is integration. That may be the reason why many tool kits support loading instance from URL. At-least I myself never came across any full featured WADO viewer.

Comment: Fully agreed. I think it is very hard to do risk and cybersecurity management for a medical product which is based on web-technology and web architectures. So I do not expect to see a serious WADO based product which is admitted for diagnostic purposes.