# e2e testing a file download and verify (assertion) the content

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, puppeteer, e2e-testing, cypress

I need to test a file download and assert that contents of the file are valid.

Tests are written in plain JS and testing tool doesn't matter. 
I have tried puppeteer, testcafe, cypress and even good old selenium with phantomJS but I am unable to get it done.

I am sure this is a very common use-case and someone out there in the wild should have already done it.

Point me to the right direction please.

Comment: First of all: what is your main issue? I suppose that you're ok with a testing framework of your choice... but aren't you able to download the file or to open and check it?
Here you can find a working download solution and then reading and checking the file should be very easy
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245080/how-to-download-file-with-puppeteer-using-headless-true
If you can try to describe better your flow and where you're stuck
Stefano