# How to download a video with Blob url with nodejs

Tags: node.js

I'm using puppeteer to get video URL but I got a blob URL. how can I download video have blob URL with Nodejs? I have try using https module but I can't download it

```
const https = require('https');
var request = https.get('blob:bloburlhere')
```

Comment: Make Puppeteer do that for you instead, since it'll have made it: blobs are a browser-internal quasi-url system. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply, do you have any sample code?

Comment: no, because it's literally "make Puppeteer do this", so look up how Puppeteer can resolve a download, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245080/how-to-download-file-with-puppeteer-using-headless-true