# Exporting File Directory Containing Files From Azure To Local Drive

Tags: c#, azure

I need a little assistance, I have a web application hosted on Azure that stores files to the directory D:\home\site\UploadeFiles, within this directory, it stores directories with a given uniqueID name, that stores all upload files from an individual.

What I would Like to do, is write a C# console application to connect to azure and download all the directories to a local directory. I am new new Azure and would like any information is possible that would help me to complete this task.

Also, if this can be done the console application that i would be write, would be set as a scheduled task to run once a day at a particular time.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: With the Azure account, are the files \ folders accessible from your windows \ LAN account normally or just accessible via the azure website?

Comment: I think through Azure, I can see them using Kudu. I tried to  connect via FTP using C#, and it throws an error. I was just wondering how I can get access to the files via a application.

Comment: do you know what media \ medium your putting the files too? Are they being passed to blob storage? or an actual file structure?

Comment: I dont mean to bombard... but whats the code for saving the files

Comment: They are being passed to the actual file structure not blob storage. So In my actual Web Application I upload to the D:\home\site\UploadeFiles and it saves the files there.

Comment: is your network extended by an azure network?

Comment: No it is not, we are just using it to Host web Applications for clients, storing documents, but we want the ability to run a sheduled task daily to download the documents customer uploaded to Azure and Save to an on Premise DB

Comment: youre only method of getting the files then will either be through a call using HTTPRequest, Client Request of something like that to grab the files down without having to download them through a browser

Comment: take a look at this answer and that will be able to help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307688/how-to-download-a-file-from-a-url-in-c

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it