# Read audio from a URL and save it

Tags: c#, asp.net, naudio

the given below code is playing audio from URL. Is it possible to read stream from that URL and create an audio file and also save in PC ?

```
var url = "http://media.ch9.ms/455884123cf7a0852876.wav";
using(var mf = new MediaFoundationReader(url))
using(var wo = new WaveOutEvent())
{
    wo.Init(mf);
    wo.Play();
    while (wo.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is C# code, not VB.NET.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download a file from a URL in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307688/how-to-download-a-file-from-a-url-in-c)

Comment: Yes it is copy obviously . and it doesnt matter code in c# or vb i can convert code c# to vb . if u have any answer so let me rather then passing useless comments

Comment: It's not a useless comment :) When you use the appropriate [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) (which I already fixed for you), your question reaches those who are interested/experts in these tags. That said, have you checked the duplicate question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this code to do that:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var url = "fake-url";
        using (var mf = new CustomWaveOutEvent(url))
        using (var wo = new WaveOutEvent())
        {
            wo.Init(mf);
            wo.Play();
            while (wo.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
```

And the class CustomWaveOutEvent is:

```
public class CustomWaveOutEvent : MediaFoundationReader
{
    private WaveFileWriter fileStream;

    public CustomWaveOutEvent(string file) : base(file)
    {
        fileStream = new WaveFileWriter("OutputFile.wav", this.WaveFormat);
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        var dataToReturn = base.Read(buffer, offset, count);

        fileStream.Write(buffer);

        return dataToReturn;
    }
}
```

I hope to be helpful