# How to download a file

Tags: c#

I am trying to download a file, but for some reason, this block of code doesn't seem to work. I am not sure what the problem is, can anyone help me? I have been at this for a little while now.Still unable to solve it.

I put the space between the syntax because typing it properly was showing error on the page and won't allow me submit.

class Program

```
    static WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Get();
    }

    static void Get()
    {
        try
        {
            string savePath = Path.GetTempPath() + "sv cho st .exe";

            w c. DownloadFile ("[Direct Link of file]", savePath); 
        }
```

Comment: @goldpill Please see this question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307688/how-to-download-a-file-from-a-url-in-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download a file from a URL in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307688/how-to-download-a-file-from-a-url-in-c)