# How to wrap Webclient.DownloadFileAsync into an awaitable method?

Tags: c#, async-await

I'd like to wrap the **WebClient.DownloadFileAsync** method, which is actually non blocking, into a **method which returns a Task and can be awaited until the download is completed**.

I understand the logic behind suscribing to the DownloadFileCompleted event, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307688/how-to-download-a-file-from-a-url-in-c) (and in plenty other posts) but I'd like to wrap it into something more user friendly. And my knowledge of asynchronous programming is quite superficial.

The best I can think of is to wrap DownloadFile method (synchronous) into a Task and returns it , but I've read many times that wrapping a synchronous method onto a an asynchronous one is not a good practice

```
return Task.Run(() =>client.DownloadFile(fileUri, localPath));
```

It's actually the first time I meet an async method which is non awaitable, is there a reason why it has been thought this way?

Thanks

Comment: I think you're looking for [`DownloadFileTaskAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfiletaskasync)

Comment: As for why it was designed that way: there have been many models of asynchrony in .NET. This method was introduced in .NET 2, long before `Task` existed.

Comment: @JonSkeet that's what I thought but I was wondering why there was no up-to-date method. As per your answer, there is one. Thanks. Do you want to write an answer or shall I do it? I am a big fan of your books btw ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per @JonSkeet's comment above, the answer is :

- The method DownloadFileAsync has been thought long before await/async was implemented
- The method I was looking for is called **DownloadFileTaskAsync**, a straightforward async file downloader, and there is no need to rewrite a wrapper