# How would I replace files in a folder (Windows Forms)?

Tags: c#, winforms

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // here i want to replace the files with the same name from a download link //
    Application.Exit();
}
```

I am fairly new to C# and this might not make sense. When the button is clicked, it should replace the files in a folder and replace them with the files from a download link or other source.

Comment: What do you mean by other source?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download a file from a URL in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307688/how-to-download-a-file-from-a-url-in-c)

Comment: Not only download, but replace the file. And by other source I mean like dropbox or mega.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
WebClient myClient = new WebClient();
myClient.DownloadFile(yourLink, YourFileLocation);
```

This should overwrite the file with the new one.
**----EDIT #1**

```
WebClient myClient = new WebClient();
myClient.DownloadFile("https://website.com/test.exe", @"C:\test.exe");
```

This should replace the test.exe on your computer with the test.exe from the website.
**----EDIT #2**

To replace the file on someone else's computer, you would make sure that when the file is downloaded, it is always in the same place on every computer. Here is an example of putting it in "My Documents"

```
WebClient myClient = new WebClient();
myClient.DownloadFile("https://website.com/test.exe", @"C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + @"\Documents\test.exe");
```

Comment: For my file location, do I put where the file is for them?

Comment: The file location is just where the file you download will be saved. Put in the location of the old file, and it will overwrite it (as long as it has the same name)

Comment: I will have other people using the program. Can you add an example of the code if it's going to replace test.exe?

Comment: What exactly are you hoping to accomplish? Are you making some kind of auto-updater?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: What if I want to replace it on someone else's computer?

Comment: @Duel I have edited your answer because in windows the directory character is `\\`

Comment: Can I use application.startup path to replace files there?

Comment: Would this work: 


            WebClient myClient = new WebClient();
            myClient.DownloadFile("https://website.com/test.exe", Application.StartupPath); or would i have to replace myclient with webclient?

Comment: That would not work. You cannot just have the path. You would need an end to the path.
WRONG: "Application.StartupPath"

Comment: RIGHT: Application.StartupPath + "/test.exe"