# loading a file from http to a local filepath temporarily using c# webclient

Tags: c#, .net, url, webclient

I want to save a file from a http link to the local drive just temporarily in order to access it, this one is working so far and I'm getting the data but a need to write this data to a local file, for example to C:\Windows\temp\test.text, this file should be deleted afterwards.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string url = "http://www.example.com/test.text";
var file = client.DownloadData(url);
```

could any one help me on this, thank you!

Comment: so do you want to write to a file of client machine? Or on the server?

Comment: on the client machine locally!

Comment: @C.Evenhuis yes i understand but i'm not an experienced programmer and many solutions seem very complicated to me :/

Comment: `WebClient` has a `DownloadFile` method.

Comment: This is what you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307688/how-to-download-a-file-from-a-url-in-c. I found it within seconds and you can do that too (amazing), use search.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write a file on client machine due to security, Any program executing in the browser executes within the browser sandbox and has access to limited features like printer, cookies, etc.

You can write the data to file as a Response object to the client's browser. The Client has the choice of whether to save it or not to his machine.