# I want to download a file from storage

Tags: azure, model-view-controller, c#-4.0, azure-storage

file path

```
https://ubj10edustgcdn.azureedge.net/userdata/documents/a09b372d-cffe-438a-b98d-123d118ac0a5/provincial management service batch.pdf
```

how can i downlaod file from this path by c#

```
var filepath ="https://ubj10edustgcdn.azureedge.net/userdata/documents/a09b372d-cffe-438a-b98d-123d118ac0a5/provincial management service batch.pdf";
return  File(filepath, "application/force-download", Path.GetFileName(filepath));
```

this code return exception that virtual path is not valid.

Comment: How about returning a 302 redirect with that URL? Or you need to start a download through a stream and return that stream in File().

Answer (score 0):

The URL contains `azureedge.net`, which means it's served from a CDN. Which also means you will not be downloading from storage, but 'just' a file from the internet.

Have a look at [How to download a file from a URL in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307688/how-to-download-a-file-from-a-url-in-c)

> ```
> using (var client = new WebClient())
> {
>    client.DownloadFile("http://example.com/file/song/a.mpeg", "a.mpeg");
> }
> ```

If you *actually* want to download a file from Azure Storage, you will need to know the (internal) path to the file and you can use code like this to download the file:

```
    string connectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnection");
    BlobContainerClient container = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, "<CONTAINER-NAME>");

    var blockBlob = container.GetBlobClient("<FILE-NAME>");
    using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite("<LOCAL-FILE-NAME>"))
    {
      blockBlob.DownloadTo(fileStream);
    }
```

Source: [Uploading and Downloading a Stream into an Azure Storage Blob](https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip76.html#download-a-file)

Comment: UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\a.mpeg' is denied. I got excepton like that

Comment: System.NotSupportedException: 'The given path's format is not supported.'
If i pass this Url "https://ubj10edustgcdn.azureedge.net/userdata/documents/a09b372d-cffe-438a-b98d-123d118ac0a5/provincial management service batch.pdf"