# C# Open a pdf from url in windows form

Tags: c#, pdf, display, windows-forms-designer, axacropdf

I want to show some pdfs on my windows form program.

When i pick a pdf that on my pc the code below is working:

```
axAcroPDF1.LoadFile("C:\\Users\\X260\\Desktop\\TP100.pdf");
```

But if i I pick a pdf from an url, the code is not working. It doesn't gives error but i just see a blank page.

```
path = "https://" + "www.massgrup.com/mask/Sertifikalar" + "/" + yol; 
axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(path);
```

How i can show a pdf from url on my windows form ?

Comment: Maybe it can be a security issue... I had a problem like that in WPF, but I decided to download the PDF in the Windows temp directory and then the PDF back to the first case (a path) and it will work

Comment: Could you share the codes to download a pdf in the windows temp ?

Comment: Sorry, when searching here in stack overflow with the words "download file C#" you'll find already half of the requested solution, please search for the rest.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307688/how-to-download-a-file-from-a-url-in-c