# Locally storing a file via POST REQUEST ASP.NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to make an ASP.NET 5 API that has a "Video" entity with four attributes:

```
    public class Video
    {
        public Guid VideoId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public long SizeInBytes { get; set; }
        public string ContentPath { get; set; }
    }
```

My questions are two:

1. Is it possible to store locally (in a folder in the solution) the file located in the path entered via POST REQUEST in the attribute `ContentPath`? If so, what is the easiest way to do this?
2. Is it possible that the attribute `SizeInBytes` is automatically set according to the size of the file located in the `ContentPath`?

Comment: Are you trying to *upload* a file to a controller?  Or something else?  It's not really clear to me what specifically you're asking or what isn't working as expected.

Comment: 1) Please elaborate what you mean. If I understand correctly you want to save it in a folder in your project then yes you can easily create a folder inside VS and add your file by using add existing file menu.
2) Yes, it's a property you can add a method to set (set section of property) which will change the value of SizeInBytes when ever the value of ContentPath is changed.

Comment: I would like to insert a URI attribute string ```ContentPath``` via POST REQUEST, and have the file located at that URI uploaded to a folder in the solution. So yes, in a way I need to upload a file to the controller. And so far nothing is working, as I don't even know if it can be done.

Comment: That means you want to download a file from other URI; Not upload it. Check download methods in this site.

Comment: @MatheusReis: If you're inputting a URL to your application and you want your application to fetch the file at that URL then what you're asking is to *download* that file.  Which would explain why you're struggling to find examples of how to do that, since you're using the wrong terminology.  In that case this may now be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/307688/328193).