How to use selenium in controller ASP.NET MVC?
I try to use selenium in my ASP.NET MVC project, but not for testing, I use selenium in my controller to open new browser and download file after click button in my website. After I click button, the browser is open but selenium driver is not working to navigate to some url(cannot open www.example.com in browser).
this is my code (I write this code in Controller, not in unit test):
private void OpenBrowser()
        {
            try
            {
                string strChromeDriver = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BinaryLocationChrome"];
                string strdownloadsPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DownloadPath"];

                var options = new ChromeOptions();
                options.AddArgument("disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");
                options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
                options.AddArgument("--remote-debugging-port=0");
                options.AddArguments("--incognito", "--disable-popup-blocking", "safebrowsing-disable-download-protection", "allow-unchecked-dangerous-downloads");
                options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", strdownloadsPath);
                options.AddUserProfilePreference("intl.accept_languages", "nl");
                options.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "true");
                options.AddArgument("--log-level=3");

                try
                {
                    var driver = new ChromeDriver(strChromeDriver, options);
                    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("www.example.com");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(">> FAILED " + " - " + e.ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("** FAILED ** " + e.ToString()); 
            }
        }

Please anyone help me to solve this problem, Thanks.

Did you see any error and is the same code working with a normal console application?

If this works, it would open the browser on the server - is that really what you want?

you should remove just about all of those options except setting download directory.  (but especially this: --remote-debugging-port=0)  There are definitely dangers involved with doing this on your server if you are not in control of the site the driver is opening.  You should consider using a separate machine and grid so you can (hopefully) secure things properly.

@Developer, the project run in port 44334 (https://localhost:44334/Default), after error that I get is "OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:55108/", do you have a solution ?

@HansKeﬆing, Yah like that, do you have a solution ?

@browsermator, I have to remove all options except download option, but the result still same, driver cannot navigate to some url, do you have a solution ?

Maybe a better question: can you explain why you want to download something by opening a browser on the server side and manipulating that through Selenium? Why not handle the download yourself directly in your controller?

you should probably use default constructor to let Selenium's driver/browser manager handle things.  But it looks like you're passing the browser path instead of the driver path there.  Browser binary path would be set in options if needed.  (and yes, you should use httpclient, as @Hans Kesting suggests, if you can... it'll be much more efficient... or even something like HTMLUnit if you can get away with it)

Are you creating a new business project to open the browser using selenium or with in the same are you creating it

What happens if you create a nunit project and run it

@HansKeﬆing, I use selenium for automation, I want to open browser to download many reports, extract and insert the value to database, if I do manually, its very wasting time.

@browsermator, ya actually I have to try to use default constructor, but always fail, now I try to look for another options, but if the first option one day possible to I will use it, because my client wants to do like that. If one day you try and success don't forget to give me info, Thanks

@Developer, yahh actually if I use nunit test, its success, but the main problem how to use nunit test after publish ? could I use nunit test after publish ? sorry, I'm still newbie to use selenium

What I meant was not doing it by hand, but like here https://stackoverflow.com/q/307688/121309
